# Safe and portable way to convert a char* to uint16_t

Tags: c, char, integer

As mentioned in the title, I'm looking for a way to convert a char* (coming from argv) to a uint16_t. The command line argument is a port number, and so, can't be > to 65535, nor negative.

Currently, I did this (compiling with -std=gnu99):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/*
 * Converts a string to an unsigned int and stores the result in "res".
 */
bool str_to_uint(const char* str, unsigned long int* res) {
    if (str[0] == '-')
        return false;
    char* first_wrong_character;
    uintmax_t result = strtoumax(str, &first_wrong_character, 10);
    if ((result == UINTMAX_MAX) && (errno == ERANGE))
        return false; // Overflow)
    if ((*str != '\0') && (*first_wrong_character != '\0'))
        return false; // Not everything has been converted
    if ((result == 0) && (str == first_wrong_character))
        return false; // Nothing to convert
    *res = result;
    return true;
}

/*
 * Converts a string to an uint16_t and stores the result in "res".
 */
bool str_to_uint16(const char* str, uint16_t* res) {
    unsigned long uint;
    if (!str_to_uint(str, &uint))
        return false;
    if (uint > UINT16_MAX)
        return false;
    *res = (uint16_t)uint;
    return true;
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, so if you could tell me what is the good way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strtol(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) that is able to return an error in case of integer overflow (`ERANGE`), and simply check if the parsed integer is not too large vs. the `uint16_t` capacity:

```
#include <stdint.h> /* fixed-width integer types */
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

static bool
str_to_uint16(const char *str, uint16_t *res)
{
  long int val = strtol(str, NULL, 10);
  if (errno == ERANGE || val > UINT16_MAX || val < 0)
    return false;
  *res = (uint16_t) val;
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Since the question concerns C99, and if I include a better error management (thanks to @nwellnhof and @chux) I would say the version below should be the right candidate:

```
#include <inttypes.h> /* strtoimax */

static bool
str_to_uint16(const char *str, uint16_t *res)
{
  char *end;
  errno = 0;
  intmax_t val = strtoimax(str, &end, 10);
  if (errno == ERANGE || val < 0 || val > UINT16_MAX || end == str || *end != '\0')
    return false;
  *res = (uint16_t) val;
  return true;
}
```

It succeeds with:

- `1981`
- `65535` (`UINT16_MAX`)

It returns a conversion error (as expected) with:

- `65536` (`UINT16_MAX+1`)
- `a1981`
- `1981a`
- `abcd`
- `9223372036854775808` (`INTMAX_MAX+1`: in such a case `ERANGE` occurs)
- `-9223372036854775809` (`INTMAX_MIN-1`: in such a case `ERANGE` occurs)

Comment: I tried this with an overflow number (65536) and I got 0 in my variable instead of getting an error. Moreover, PRIu16 is "%u" and not "%hu" (h = short). BTW, I don't know why PRIu16 is not %hu.

Comment: I've updated my answer: `sscanf` is indeed not a good idea because it can't protect from integer overflow. `strtol` is thus the right candidate (see above).

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to use `strtoumax`. I'd go with the more portable `strtol`. The error handling can also be simplified to something like this:

```
bool str_to_uint16(const char *str, uint16_t *res) {
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long val = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if (errno || end == str || *end != '\0' || val < 0 || val >= 0x10000) {
        return false;
    }
    *res = (uint16_t)val;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You error management (vs the `end` checks) is better than mine :) But I guess you meant `0x10000` instead of `0x1000` for the upper bound, right?

Comment: In this case what's the goal of strtoumax() ? Why not use strtoul in your example ? And what is 0x1000 ?

Comment: Right, I meant `0x10000`. Fixed.

Comment: `val > UINT16_MAX` would be better.

Comment: Not sure what's up with `errno`

Answer (score 0):

I made it very simple and not need conversion, only using a pointer.

```
uint16_t mat[7] = { 0x111A,0x121A,0x131A,0x141A,0x151A,0x161A,0x171A };
uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&mat[0];
```

The test of the conversion is here:

```
int main()
{

    uint16_t mat[7] = { 0x111A,0x121A,0x131A,0x141A,0x151A,0x161A,0x171A };
    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&mat[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%04X 0x%02X%02X\n", mat[i], ptr[2 * i +1], ptr[2 * i]);//ojo, ORDEN INVERTIDO
    }
 
    cout << "*** FIN ***" << endl; (void)getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```